# HTML design not working in WPF

Tags: html, wpf, html-table

I created a Webpage in HTML and designed it using `<Table>` HTML tab. Normally it works perfect, but on loading the Page in WPF application the Layout gets disturbed.

What is best approach  to design the html other than table such that when it is embedded in wpf application using webbrowser control the design does not distort?

Answer (score -2):

since the webbrowser control you embedd in WPF is the internetexplorer, your webpage must be designed to run on IE.

flusser

Comment: My page is Designed through table attribute in HTML. when i am opening it in webbrowser it is not showing any scrollbar but when the same is opened inside the wpf window it comes with scroll bar with design distort. on removing scrollbar some area get clipped. How to make my HTML page content fit inside wpf window without scrollbar and without clipping of any area ? can someone suggest any other design approach other than table or any HTML tag that would help me to achieve it .